# Combining func_get_args, call_user_func_array, and Pass By Reference

Tags: php, module, hook, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm doing something a bit tricky in PHP 5.3.29 today. I'm in a scenario where I have to chain `func_get_args`, `call_user_func_array`, and pass **some** of the arguments by reference.

An attempt at a simplified scenario looks like this:

**caller.php**

```
//* Caller Setup *//
// Define which Modules call which Hooks
global $hooks = array(
    'hookA' => array('moduleA', 'moduleB'),
    'hookB' => array('moduleA')
);

// Generically calls any Hook for all Modules
function caller_call_hook($hook, $by_reference = array())
{
    // Use Hooks Array
    global $hooks;

    // Initialize Return Array
    $values = array();

    // Determine the Arguments for the Function Call
    $args = func_get_args();

    // Remove $hook and $by_reference from the Arguments
    unset($args[0], $args[1]);
    $args = array_values($args); // Collapse Array

    // Map specified Arguments by Reference
    foreach($by_reference as $index)
        $args[$index] =& $args[$index];

    // Call each Embedded Hook
    foreach($hooks[$hook] as $module)
        $values[$module] = call_user_func_array($module . '_' . $hook, $args);

    // Return all Values
    return $values;
}

//* Caller Triggers *//
function caller_hook_A($paramA, $paramB)
{
    caller_call_hook('hook_A', array(), $paramA, $paramB);
}

function caller_hook_B(&$paramA)
{
    caller_call_hook('hook_B', array(0), $paramA);
}
```

**moduleA.php**

```
function moduleA_hook_A($paramA, $paramB) { ... }
function moduleA_hook_B(&$paramA) { ... }
```

**moduleB.php**

```
function moduleB_hook_A($paramA, $paramB) { ... }
```

Doing all of this throws the warning:

```
Warning: Parameter 1 to moduleA_hook_B() expected to be a reference, value given in caller_call_hook()
```

How can I make this work as intended?

---

Just to provide some background as to what's actually going on here:

I'm working in a framework where `caller_hook_*` is called by the framework. I'm essentially using the *caller* as a make-shift "Code Hub", where the various features within my code are handled separately.

And no, I can't split this project into multiple projects. That's a restriction that has been placed upon me. Normally, that would be the route I'd take.

The `module*` functions are basically internal features that I want to be able to switch on and off with ease. They're intentionally separate files as the modules themselves have no crossover, other than that they sometimes use the same hooks.

All of the configuration for the hooks themselves are handled in the `$hooks` variable *(This is a simplified version. Normally there's also function attributes per module, module attributes, etc., but that's not needed for this particular problem.)*.

I'm trying to keep this generalized as much as possible. I know that I could shove everything in the respective `caller_hook_*` functions, but as this project grows these hooks will become cumbersome to maintain if the independent features are clumped together.

Some of the hooks use **Pass-By-Reference** on some of their arguments, hence I need to be able to specify which ones. Everything I have done so far works for all **Pass-By-Value** only functions.

I also don't want to use *call-time pass-by-reference*.

Comment: What is `$args[$index] =& $args[$index]` supposed to do? How can something be a reference to itself?

Comment: Should that be `$args[$index] =& $by_reference[$index];`?

Comment: I come from a C++ background, so I may be using references incorrectly here. What would you recommend?

Comment: I don't see how that explains anything. You wouldn't set a reference to itself in C++, either.

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to do is change the element in the array to be passed by reference. How is that accomplished?

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. Why don't `caller_hook_A` and `caller_hook_B` use their arguments when they call `caller_call_hook`?

Comment: You also have an undefined variable `$hooks` in `caller_call_hook`. Either move the assignment of `$hooks` into the function, or add `global $hooks;` to the function.

Comment: As per your first comment, you are correct. That's an oversight on my end. As per your second, again, you are correct. That's from using a simplified version, rather than my complex one that used a bunch of methods from the framework. I'll correct those.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this to work, albeit an odd solution.

I was on the right track, just slightly off.

I changed this:

```
// Map specified Arguments by Reference
foreach($by_reference as $index)
    $args[$index] =& $args[$index];
```

to this:

```
// Map specified Arguments by Reference
$refs = array();

foreach($args as $key => &$value)
    $refs[$key] =& $value;
```

and this:

```
// Call each Embedded Hook
foreach($hooks[$hook] as $module)
    $values[$module] = call_user_func_array($module . '_' . $hook, $args);
```

to this:

```
// Call each Embedded Hook
foreach($hooks[$hook] as $module)
    $values[$module] = call_user_func_array($module . '_' . $hook, $refs);
```

It's a bit of a weird fix, but it does the job. It turns out that I don't need the `$by_reference` variable.